# call javascript function before clear browsing data

Tags: javascript

Hi,
will it possible to call a javascript-function before clearing the browsing data.
actually we have window.unload to call before browser close.
I want to call javascript-function before we do clear browsing data.is it possible?
Thanks In advance

Comment: as in, when the user clears their cookies etc? If so, *no*, this is not possible.

Comment: okey thanks Matt.is there alternative solutions for it? actually i need to send the logoutTime to server before clear the browsing cache.

Comment: You never can rely on such logout things. What would happen if one deletes cookies after cutting the internet connection? The only reliable thing is when the user visits your server the next time without cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only one way you can be "notified" about this way of logout: you need a periodic ping from the client to the server and the server will notice when that ping stops happening. Of course it happens when the browser is closed or crashed but I don't think you can get 100% correct results for what you want. You can polish this by some extra logic, for example register a "possible logout" event when the ping stops and if next time you find the same user to be logged in (when they navigate to your site again) then remove the "possible logout" event if next time the user has to log in again then convert it to "real logout" event.

Thinking more about this: I don't know why you want to register all kind of logouts but even if you could do what you are asking for what if the user was logged in from different browsers/clients and logs out from one of them? That doesn't clear their cookie on the other client so they are not fully logged out yet. Depending why you need to register their logged in time this may cause problems for you.